# Recover the first half of the time-domain signal of the N-point frequency domain signal using an N/2-point FFT

Tags: fft, frequency-domain, ifft, time-domain

Let X be an N-point sequence in the frequency domain (where N is a power of two):
$$ X = (X[0], ..., X[N-1]) $$
where $X$ is the complex and conjugate symmetric forward DFT of the real sequence $x = (x[0], ..., x[N-1])$.

I am interested in using a single half-sized ($\frac{N}{2}$) FFT to compute the sequence $x_{h1} = (x[0], \ldots, x[\frac{N}{2}-1])$.

I can recover the sequence $x_{even} = (x[0], x[2], ..., x[N-2])$ using a single half-sized ($\frac{N}{2}$) by exploiting the DIT algorithm for FFT like so:
$$ x_{even} = F^{-1}(\frac{X_{h1} + X_{h2}}{2}), $$
where $X_{h1}$ and $X_{h2}$ are defined as:
$$ X_{h1} = X[0], ..., X[\frac{N}{2} - 1] $$
$$ X_{h2} = X[\frac{N}{2}], ..., X[N - 1] $$

**Question:**

I am curious if some symmetry exists that makes it possible to calculate $x_{h1}$ using a single half-sized $\left( \frac{N}{2} \right)$ FFT (whether  $X_{even}$, $X_{odd}$, or any other $N/2$-sized combination or manipulation of the elements of $X$).

UPDATE: I am aware that you can recover the entire sequence $x$ using a packed FFT of length $\frac{N}{2}$ as illustrated by *Rabiner* in the paper *On the Use of Symmetry in FFT Computation*, however, the question is about recovering $x_{h1}$ only.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's not clear if you want to use $X_{even}$ and $X_{odd}$, or if you want to use any $N/2$ subset of $X$, or something else.

Comment: I have edited to clarify any subset of X.

Comment: @user295357 that approach recovers all of x(n), I specifically am interested in computing exactly half of it and no more.

Comment: @Dan Boschen, I am aware of this technique. have updated my question to clarify that the output should be $x_{h1}$ only.

Comment: @keith Got it! I deleted my comment (and will this one as well) to clean up the thread.